# How to retrieve detailed information when AWS error are vague

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to know how to search details when error is vague in AWS. In below example I would like to know which permission is missing or which operation was performed.

```
Terminated with errors 
Service role bundle-release-import-AWSDataPipelineRole has insufficient EC2 permissions.
EC2 Message: AmazonEC2Exception: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
(Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 403; Error Code: UnauthorizedOperation; 
Request ID: e2614d7b-ef8f-467d-81cf-14ee9c4671c8; Proxy: null)
```

Comment: What generated this message? Some services provide more information in "detail" logs. Some, unfortunately, don't.

Comment: An EMR instance thrown that error. It was request for creation by data pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

Option 1: Use Athena queries to troubleshoot IAM permission API call failures by searching AWS CloudTrail logs

Option 2: Use the AWS CLI to troubleshoot IAM permission API call failures

for more details on how to implement each option you can refer to the article below

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/troubleshoot-iam-permission-errors/

Comment: Ooooohhh, that's a bingoooo! As Hans Landa tend to say. Thank you for help.